# Issue with calling a javascript file from a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard

I have two files, one called TestKeyboard.html, from which I call the javascript code file AutomaticKeyboardChange.js.
Here is the html page :

```
<html>
    <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

            <title> including file </title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/mounaim/Desktop/Javascript Tests/AutomaticKeyboardChange.js"> </script>
    </head> 
        <body>
                <p id="demo"> Here I'm testing some code with javascript </p> <br/><br/><br/>

                <input id="firstname" type="text" > </input>
        </body>


</html>
```

and here is the javascript file :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
var KEYS_MAP = {

            65 :"ض",

            90 :"ص",

            69 :"ث",


            82 :"ق",


            84 :"ف",


            89 :"غ",


            85 :"ع",


            73 :"ه",


            79 :"خ",


            80 :"ح",


            221 :"ج",


            81 :"ش",


            83 :"س",


            68 :"ي",


            70 :"ب",


            71 :"ل",


            72 :"ا",


            74 :"ت",


            75 :"ن",


            76 :"م",


            77 :"ك",


            192 :"ط",


            220 :"ذ",


            87 :"ئ",


            88 :"ء",


            67 :"ؤ",


            86 :"ر",


            66 :"ل",


            78 :"ى",


            188 :"ة",


            190 :"و",


            191 :"ز",


            223 :"ظ",

            186 : "د"

   };
//Ici à la place de "firstname" faites rentrer l'id du champ pour lequel on veut activer la conversion
document.getElementById("firstname").onkeydown = function myFunction(e){
  var keyCode = window.event ? window.event.keyCode : e.which;
  if(keyCode == 66) {
              this.value += "ل";
              this.value +="ا"
              return false;
  }

  else{
      if(keyCode && KEYS_MAP[keyCode]){
              this.value += KEYS_MAP[keyCode];
              return false;
    }
  };
}
}



</script>
```

When I load the HTML page, the script is not running ! why ?
Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your js file is being really loaded ( check browser's network tab).

This absolute path might also be a reason for the problem, why don't you put the js in the same location of your HTML file, so you can call it like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="AutomaticKeyboardChange.js"></script>
```

2)you dont need the script tag inside your javascript file.

Comment: thank you @artdias90 this worked I've ommited the scrpt tag and include just the relative path.

Answer (score 1):

you are directly referencing a javascript using it's physical path.  This would only work if you were loading the html file from a windows file explorer not from a web server.  The path must be with respect to virtual path.

Try just loading the javascript file and remove the "C:/Users/mounaim/Desktop/Javascript Tests/AutomaticKeyboardChange.js" stuff